# Dynamically append dropdown's value text to another dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<select id="mg_sport_game_id1">
   <option value="">Select</option>
   <option value="25">Titans</option>
   <option value="35">Batman</option>
</select>
```

**Now I have to fetch the above dropdown's value and append its value,text to other dropdown**

```
<select id="schedule_winner">
   <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

**I am trying as follows**

```
var team1=$("#mg_sport_game_id1").val();
var myOptions = {
    guest_name : guest,
    ($("#mg_sport_game_id1").options[$("#mg_sport_game_id1").selectedIndex].text) : team1
};

$.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {
    $('#schedule_winner').append( new Option(text,val) );
});
```

*I am ending up with following error :*

> SyntaxError: invalid property id

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So, whenever the user selects an option from the first `<select>`, that option will be added to the second `<select>`?

Comment: yes thats the requirement @showdev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to achive, but maybe this can help you:

```
$('#mg_sport_game_id1').on('change', function() {

  var val = $(this).val(),
    text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();

  $('#schedule_winner').append(new Option(text, val));

});
```

What I do here:

- Register an event handler for the change event
- get the value and text from the selected option.
- Append the new Option to the other `select`

---

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/vzy6qjn7/)

Answer (score 1):

I you want to copy all the option of the first select to the second one you don't have to use `each()` function, just simply copy the html code :

```
$('#schedule_winner').html($('#mg_sport_game_id1').html());
```

If you want to do it using `each()` method :

```
$('#mg_sport_game_id1 option').each(function(){
    $('#schedule_winner')
          .append('<option value="'+$(this).val()+'">'+$(this).text()+'</option>');
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#schedule_winner').html($('#mg_sport_game_id1').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mg_sport_game_id1">
   <option value="">Select</option>
   <option value="25">Titans</option>
   <option value="35">Batman</option>
</select>

<select id="schedule_winner">
   <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or even this would work,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#mg_sport_game_id1').change(function(){
    $('#schedule_winner').append(new Option(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text, this.options[this.selectedIndex].value));
});
});
```